# Can (Everstart 400W) to a kicker zx150.? 2 car amplifier? Situation: I want to use my iphone and Bluetooth speakers(Dolphin sp-212RBT) in my SUV

Tags: amplifier, inverter, speakers, inverting-amplifier

Home inverter battery is 12 volt, I want to buy only a sub-woofer system.
can I directly connect the car audio amplifier system to the battery 12V of my home inverter system?

Answer (score 2):

No. Unless you are mixing your terms, power inverters are used to convert DC to AC. Your car amplifier likely uses 12-13.8 VDC, and your inverter outputs 120/230 VAC.

Does your inverter look something like this?

[image: power inverter]

If your inverter has DC input wires (instead of the power jack cable), you can likely - assuming it requires ~12V input - wire it directly. And if your amplifier is AC, then you should be able to plug it in. You'll have to check the specs to know if your inverter has enough power output to drive your amplifier.

Comment: i mean directly to the battery

Comment: Edited per your comment

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can if your car amplifier operates on 12V DC.But you should be aware that your car amplifier operates on 12V DC or not. Car amplifier may take 3 input power supply. 1: 12 volt Dc. 2: ground and 3: ignition (12 v). check your amplifier specification provided by the manufacturer company.
if you are planning to use from battery power supply i think connecting ignition input to battery directly will consume extra power which is not a good practice but check specification provided by manufacturer company for more detail.